# get text from html with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i have htmlcode how to get the 700 mAh as array[0], BL-5CA as array[2],  Nokia as array[3] using PHP. itry like this

```
preg_match_all('~<span>capacity(.*?)mAh~si', $result, $matches[0]);
preg_match_all('~<span>Model(.*?)</span></div>~si', $result, $matches[1]);
preg_match_all('~<span>Brand(.*?)</span></div>~si', $result, $matches[2]);
```

it shows me empty array. please help me to fix it

```
<div class="b-goods-specifications mod_cutted"> <div class="b-goods-specifications-item"> <ul class="b-goods-specifications-list"> <li class = "b-goods-specifications-row g-clearfix "> <div class="b-goods-specifications-cell"> <span> **capacity** </ span> </ div> <div class="b-goods-specifications-cell"> **700 mAh** </ div> </ li> <li class="b-goods-specifications-row g-clearfix"> <div class="b-goods-specifications-cell"> <span> **Model** </ span> </ div > <div class="b-goods-specifications-cell"> **BL-5CA** </ div> </ li> <li class="b-goods-specifications-row g-clearfix"> <div class = "b-goods-specifications-cell "> <span> **Brand** </ span> </ div> <div class="b-goods-specifications-cell"> **Nokia** </ div> </ li> <li class =" b-goods -specifications-row g-clearfix "> <div class="b-goods-specifications-cell"> <span> Type </ span> </ div> <div class="b-goods-specifications-cell"> Li -ion ​​</ div> </ li> </ ul> </ div> </ div>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php - don't use regex for HTML.  http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ is an easy-to-use external library to use if you can't figure out PHP DOM.

Comment: not saying that this is the correct way, but if you MUST use a regex remove all the `\r` and `\n`from the input string, they screw up the regex

Comment: also you have  a ton of \s in your input string yet none in the regex

Answer (score 1):

Use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), it will be simpler than regular expression.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php